# What is wrong with this go code, and what is os.Stdin?

Tags: go

```
  1 package main                                                                                                          
  2                                                                                                                       
  3 import (                                                                                                              
  4         "bufio"                                                                                                       
  5         "fmt"                                                                                                         
  6         "os"                                                                                                          
  7 )                                                                                                                     
  8                                                                                                                       
  9 func main() {                                                                                                         
 10         input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)                                                                           
 11         if input.Scan == 1 {                                                                                          
 12                 fmt.println("true")                                                                                   
 13         }                                                                                                             
 14 }
```

I want create something that will ask for user input, then check if that user input = 1

Answer (score 3):

The Scan code documentation says:

```
//Scan advances the Scanner to the next token, which will then be
//available through the Bytes or Text method. It returns false when the
//scan stops, either by reaching the end of the input or an error.
```

So you could do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if input.Scan() && input.Text() == "1" {
        fmt.Println("true")
    }
}
```

The os.Stdin is how you make your Scanner get it's input from the stdin.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#/media/File:Stdstreams-notitle.svg)

One note, pay attention for uppercase letters for exported functions.
On line 12 you wrote

```
fmt.println
```

and it should be

```
fmt.Println
```

You should go to 
https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1
to get started with golang.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, this fixed most of my questions, like number notation if syntax and much more. props to rcmgleite

Comment: @liam, could you Mark it as accepted if you believe this is the correct answer?